# My Loop In JS Won't Work For A Mystifying Reason

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

Ive been studing JS for 2 month and my teacher gave this assignment so as usuall i solve it but here i tried many hours but i can't Although that i'm pretty sure my answer logically is right but i don't know why the `name` repeated just one time

The Required Output is :

`String [Osama], [Mohamed], [Ali], [Ibrahim] => Done !`

Important Note : The `[]` isn't an array

```js
/*
  Function Arrow Challenges
*/

// [1] One Statement In Function
// [2] Convert To Arrow Function
// [3] Print The Output [Arguments May Change]

let names = function (...name) {
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    return `String [${name[i]}], => Done ~`
}};

console.log(names("Osama", "Mohamed", "Ali", "Ibrahim"));
// String [Osama], [Mohamed], [Ali], [Ibrahim] => Done !
```

Question : How could i solve this ? **with a logical explain to the answer**

Answer (score -2):

try to add `String [${name[i]}], => Done ~` into variable , for example

```
var S+=`String [${name[i]}], => Done ~`
return S;
```

```js
/*
  Function Arrow Challenges
*/

// [1] One Statement In Function
// [2] Convert To Arrow Function
// [3] Print The Output [Arguments May Change]

let names = function (...name) {
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    return `String [${name[i]}], => Done ~`
}};

console.log(names("Osama", "Mohamed", "Ali", "Ibrahim"));
// String [Osama], [Mohamed], [Ali], [Ibrahim] => Done !
```

Comment: your answer is wrong this is not the output i need